# Application insights | Looking at end-to-end transaction details things show up out of order?

Tags: .net, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, .net-4.8

On my webapp I added a Log message (using Serilog with ApplicationInsights sink) that runs before any DB calls are made. When testing in localhost I can confirm the message appears before any DB logs appear.

When I deploy and look at app insights for that end-to-end transaction details most of the times I see first some Azure SQL dependencies entries and only after that my 'start log' trace. It doesn't seem to be lacking precision on the timestamps because they actually are at different milliseconds.

The order the log appears is also not consistent in multiple samples, sometimes it's after 2 db calls, sometimes after 7, etc. I would expect to see my log message in order with the SQL logs.

Is this a problem with appInsights messing up my data? Or maybe the way I use Serilog to send the message to appInsights? Any tips or tricks on what's going on and how to fix it?

Serilog is configured like this:

```
loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
                                TelemetryConfiguration.Active,
                                TelemetryConverter.Traces);
```

Comment: I also am using Application Insights, but using the built in logger and ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore Nuget package. All my logs are in order and I don't see the same problems. Maybe review the Serilog options to see if its doing something strange. My setup looks very similar to the following from MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger

Comment: @AlfaTeK, it would help if you could attach a screenshot to show the problem.

Comment: @AlfaTek, try to use the **Serilog Enricher** to add a Current activity to application insights. It reduces the timestamp mismatches in Application Insights. Refer [blog](https://oleh-zheleznyak.blogspot.com/2019/08/serilog-with-application-insights.html) for the details information